# Working with dynamic HTML and Firefox issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox

Using the latest version of the FireFox (40.0.3) on Mac:

Run the following code:

```
$(function() { 
        var $sc = $('<script id="tempScript" type="text/template"/>');  
        $("body").append($sc);
        $("<div><h3>Hi</h3></div>").appendTo($sc);
});
```

Then in the console run:

```
$("#tempScript").html()
```

Actual result:
result is "undefined"

Expected result:
It should have returned: `"<div><h3>Hi</h3></div>"`

This is very serious problem and has effected a lot of our web applications functionality. Basically has broken a lot of pages of our applications.

Is there a workaround for this?
We would have to use Javascript to generate the dynamic content.

**UPDATE**:
I changed the script tag to a hidden DIV and Firefox started to respond. This is a good workaround for the time being, but I am surprised why Firefox would not handle the situation correctly when script template is used.

Comment: Did you mean to use this function `$.getScript(url, callback)`?

Comment: `#tempScript` is a script tag. Why do you think `.html()` would return anything?

Comment: First of all it works the same way on Div tags too, secondly I am specifying the type of "text/template" which is a common use case for HTML 5 templates.

Comment: but your script tag is empty - it can't return any html..

Comment: Also, `<script>` [is not a self closing tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/69913/why-dont-self-closing-script-tags-work). You'll want `<script id="tempScript" type="text/template"><script>` with either a src attribute or some js content inside of it

Comment: @neilsimp1 jQuery deals with that, it's not an issue.

Comment: I think you're after `$sc.append( $("<div><h3>Hi</h3></div>") );` or `$sc.append("<div><h3>Hi</h3></div>");` => [http://jsfiddle.net/2qvgwdvj/](http://jsfiddle.net/2qvgwdvj/)

Comment: @sam360 not that tag - it's an empty tag that you've appended. It has no content so `.html()`  **should** return undefined.

Comment: @Popnoodles works perfectly in Chrome and Safari! and I am appending the content to the script tag correctly!

Comment: You're appending the script tag (moving it from body) to `$("<div><h3>Hi</h3></div>")` which doesn't have any reference by which you can get it back. **Edit** no, you went and fixed that part of the question. Any more typos in there?

Comment: @Popnoodles That's cool, I didn't know that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out Firefox does not handle dynamically added script text/template tag and cannot return its HTML content in Javascript (Chrome and Safari work fine).

I changed the script tag to a hidden DIV and Firefox started to respond. This is a good workaround for the time being, but I am surprised why Firefox would not handle the situation correctly when script template is used.